# deallocated controller called after dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, view, modal-dialog

I have a modal view which is launched from the current view controller, as

```
[self presentModalViewCOntroller:modalViewController animated:TRUE];
```

The modal view controller dismisses itself when someone hits a button.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
```

A couple of screens later, I attempt to swap the root view within the window. I do this all the time with no trouble. But in a certain case, when switching the one view within the window, the picker delegate method is being called on the modal view controller even thought it was dismissed a while ago.

This is very strange because the modal view controller is usually deallocated when dismissModalViewController is called.

Why is a view from the modal view controller being invoked?
It appears that someone, probably the window still has a reference. Are you supposed to do something else in addition to dismissModalViewController?

Thanks

Comment: What picker is calling it? Is it a picker that should still be around, or is it one thatn should have been destroyed?

Comment: Its a picker that was on the modal view which was dismissed and should no longer be around.

Answer (score 0):

DismissModalViewController should be enough. It does seem like you have a problem with some reference hanging around that you don't intend. Without seeing more code, I can't point to anything specific.